# Why can't I click Listen to Music in Windows 7 for Bluetooth headphones?

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, music, headphones

[image: listen to music broken]

Here is a screenshot of where *Listen to Music* appears. I cannot click it, it simply does nothing if clicked. Alternately while in Playback Devices > Sound I cannot right click and press "connect".

Why can't I click this operation?

Answer (score 3):

It now works!

[image: listen to music works!]

Ultimately I've found this to be a driver-related issue. If you've tried everything else try this:

1. Figure out whose Bluetooth hardware you are using. In my case I'm using Intel-based hardware.
2. Go to their website and download/install the latest drivers available. In my case the latest drivers did *not* fix the problem. I actually had to use the older Bluetooth drivers installer.

   - I downloaded and installed the Intel Driver Update Utility
   - Once the utility is open click Scan
   - Try the *Latest drivers* and if that doesn't fix it, try the *Older drivers*

     [image: Older Drivers Tab]

As noted above I ended up having to use the *Older drivers* tab as seen in the image.

Everything works great now!

Comment: For me, even with Intel Bluetooth drivers installed (I have a Intel Bluetooth indeed), I still see `Generic Bluetooth Adapter` in Device Manager: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIx13.png. What is shown in your case? In my case, it still fails to connect a headset.

Answer (score 0):

On my Lenovo Thinkpad, I tried various versions of the Intel driver (both `bt_19.0.1607_64_win7.exe` as mentioned in the other answer and `bt_21.40.5_64_win7.exe`), and none of them worked: clicking on **"Listen to music"** did not work, it did nothing. (By the way the Device Manager showed `Generic Bluetooth Adapter` in `Bluetooth Radios`, but the other connected Bluetooth devices in the Device Manager used the right Intel driver; anyway audio was still not working).

Finally, using the driver *"Bluetooth with Enhanced Data Rate Software II for Windows"* from https://download.lenovo.com/eol/ or from https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/fr/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t420/downloads/driver-list was the only working solution (after a few hours of search!)

Then Bluetooth audio headphones are working.