# Restore Bluetooth on a Lenovo Thinkpad with Windows

Tags: windows, laptop, bluetooth, thinkpad

I double-checked that Bluetooth is Enabled in the BIOS of my Lenovo Thinkpad. Still it is invisible in Windows:

- `Device manager` doesn't have any "Bluetooth device" (I also checked with "Show hidden devices)
- `Services`: I checked that all Bluetooth services are in Automatic and Started in Windows
- I have done <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> but still the laptop's Bluetooth LED isn't green  (near the Wifi green LED)
- I am sure that the laptop is equipped of a BT adapter
- I have installed the latest Lenovo Thinkpad drivers for Bluetooth
- I have tried to go to Setup, disable BT in the BIOS, boot Windows, reboot to Setup, re-enable BT in the BIOS, boot Windows with the hope it will see a "New device" - not working
- I have tried nirsoft's tool `BluetoothCL.exe`, and it shows nothing

I know that BT worked in previous Windows installations, so what are the last solutions that could be tested to finally **restore Bluetooth on a Lenovo Laptop with Windows**?

---

PS: I spent more than one hour on this, so now I found the solution I share it with "Answer your own question" feature!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, it seems I had tried everything, but this was the only solution that worked:

- Reboot on Linux (even with a Live CD, for example Ubuntu)
- Enable Bluetooth there (<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) and try that it works
- Reboot to Windows
- Bluetooth is permanently restored!

Source: https://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=106987#p698846

Also in order to get Bluetooth Audio working, see [Why can't I click Listen to Music in Windows 7 for Bluetooth headphones?](https://superuser.com/questions/1149615/why-cant-i-click-listen-to-music-in-windows-7-for-bluetooth-headphones).